# Logo image does not show up in react

Tags: reactjs

In my react app, I tried displaying an image as a logo of my website in top navigation bar as follows:

1. I copied `logo.png` in the same folder as my `NavBar.jsx`.
2. Added following in `NavBar`

   ```
   <img
       src={logo}
       width="30"
       height="30"
   />
   ```

It gets displayed correctly when I browse `http://localhost:9001/`, but when I try accessing inner pages, say `http://localhost:9001/courseware/course/`, it shows broken image.

Then I tried to try it another way. I copied the image in `public/images/logo.png` and then trying displaying it as:

```
import logo from "./logo.png";
<img
   src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.png`}
   width="30"
   height="30"
/>
```

But now it does not show up on any page.
What I am doing wrong?

PS: I am running this app from vscode debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to use image in your element, you have to import it before. You can not use variable in `src{}` without importing. Import it with complete address, then use it with the name you wrote, in `src{}`.